# How to do an fetch request with expressions like this on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-data

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1) has an example on how to retrieve simple values only, rather than managed objects. This remembers a lot SQL using aliases and functions to only retrieve calculated values. So, actually pretty geeky stuff. To get the minimum date from a bunch of records, this is used on the mac:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

// Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

// Create an expression for the key path.
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"creationDate"];

// Create an expression to represent the minimum value at the key path 'creationDate'
NSExpression *minExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

// Create an expression description using the minExpression and returning a date.
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

// The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value.
[expressionDescription setName:@"minDate"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:minExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

// Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
else {
    if ([objects count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Minimum date: %@", [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"minDate"];
    }
}

[expressionDescription release];
[request release];
```

Nice, I though - but having a deep look into [NSExpression -expressionForFunction:arguments:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:) it turns out that iPhone OS does NOT support the `min:` function.

**Well, probably there's a nifty way to use an own function for this kind of stuff on the iPhone as well?** Because on thing I'm already worrying about is, how I'm gonna sort a table based on the calculated distance of targets on a map (location-based stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own function, then use

```
+ (NSExpression *)expressionForFunction:(NSExpression *)target selectorName:(NSString *)name arguments:(NSArray *)parameters
```

this returns an expression which will return the result of invoking on a given target a selector with a given name using given arguments.

Answer (score 0):

thnx @dontwatchmyprofile

I just tested

```
NSExpression *maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

seems to be working fine with iOS 3.2 SDK.